# How can i enumerate methods inside this class?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.5

When i check via debug, i can see the methods and variables but no matter what solution i have tried posted on stackoverflow failed

Here how i can see the methods with debug

[image]

Here the class

```
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public sealed partial class PlayerStats : pb::IMessage<PlayerStats>
{
    /// <summary>Field number for the "level" field.</summary>
    public const int LevelFieldNumber = 1;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "experience" field.</summary>
    public const int ExperienceFieldNumber = 2;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "prev_level_xp" field.</summary>
    public const int PrevLevelXpFieldNumber = 3;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "next_level_xp" field.</summary>
    public const int NextLevelXpFieldNumber = 4;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "km_walked" field.</summary>
    public const int KmWalkedFieldNumber = 5;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "pokemons_encountered" field.</summary>
    public const int PokemonsEncounteredFieldNumber = 6;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "unique_pokedex_entries" field.</summary>
    public const int UniquePokedexEntriesFieldNumber = 7;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "pokemons_captured" field.</summary>
    public const int PokemonsCapturedFieldNumber = 8;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "evolutions" field.</summary>
    public const int EvolutionsFieldNumber = 9;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "poke_stop_visits" field.</summary>
    public const int PokeStopVisitsFieldNumber = 10;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "pokeballs_thrown" field.</summary>
    public const int PokeballsThrownFieldNumber = 11;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "eggs_hatched" field.</summary>
    public const int EggsHatchedFieldNumber = 12;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "big_magikarp_caught" field.</summary>
    public const int BigMagikarpCaughtFieldNumber = 13;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "battle_attack_won" field.</summary>
    public const int BattleAttackWonFieldNumber = 14;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "battle_attack_total" field.</summary>
    public const int BattleAttackTotalFieldNumber = 15;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "battle_defended_won" field.</summary>
    public const int BattleDefendedWonFieldNumber = 16;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "battle_training_won" field.</summary>
    public const int BattleTrainingWonFieldNumber = 17;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "battle_training_total" field.</summary>
    public const int BattleTrainingTotalFieldNumber = 18;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "prestige_raised_total" field.</summary>
    public const int PrestigeRaisedTotalFieldNumber = 19;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "prestige_dropped_total" field.</summary>
    public const int PrestigeDroppedTotalFieldNumber = 20;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "pokemon_deployed" field.</summary>
    public const int PokemonDeployedFieldNumber = 21;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "pokemon_caught_by_type" field.</summary>
    public const int PokemonCaughtByTypeFieldNumber = 22;

    /// <summary>Field number for the "small_rattata_caught" field.</summary>
    public const int SmallRattataCaughtFieldNumber = 23;

    private static readonly pb::MessageParser<PlayerStats> _parser =
        new pb::MessageParser<PlayerStats>(() => new PlayerStats());

    private int battleAttackTotal_;
    private int battleAttackWon_;
    private int battleDefendedWon_;
    private int battleTrainingTotal_;
    private int battleTrainingWon_;
    private int bigMagikarpCaught_;
    private int eggsHatched_;
    private int evolutions_;
    private long experience_;
    private float kmWalked_;
    private int level_;
    private long nextLevelXp_;
    private int pokeballsThrown_;
    private pb::ByteString pokemonCaughtByType_ = pb::ByteString.Empty;
    private int pokemonDeployed_;
    private int pokemonsCaptured_;
    private int pokemonsEncountered_;
    private int pokeStopVisits_;
    private int prestigeDroppedTotal_;
    private int prestigeRaisedTotal_;
    private long prevLevelXp_;
    private int smallRattataCaught_;
    private int uniquePokedexEntries_;

    public PlayerStats()
    {
        OnConstruction();
    }

    public PlayerStats(PlayerStats other) : this()
    {
        level_ = other.level_;
        experience_ = other.experience_;
        prevLevelXp_ = other.prevLevelXp_;
        nextLevelXp_ = other.nextLevelXp_;
        kmWalked_ = other.kmWalked_;
        pokemonsEncountered_ = other.pokemonsEncountered_;
        uniquePokedexEntries_ = other.uniquePokedexEntries_;
        pokemonsCaptured_ = other.pokemonsCaptured_;
        evolutions_ = other.evolutions_;
        pokeStopVisits_ = other.pokeStopVisits_;
        pokeballsThrown_ = other.pokeballsThrown_;
        eggsHatched_ = other.eggsHatched_;
        bigMagikarpCaught_ = other.bigMagikarpCaught_;
        battleAttackWon_ = other.battleAttackWon_;
        battleAttackTotal_ = other.battleAttackTotal_;
        battleDefendedWon_ = other.battleDefendedWon_;
        battleTrainingWon_ = other.battleTrainingWon_;
        battleTrainingTotal_ = other.battleTrainingTotal_;
        prestigeRaisedTotal_ = other.prestigeRaisedTotal_;
        prestigeDroppedTotal_ = other.prestigeDroppedTotal_;
        pokemonDeployed_ = other.pokemonDeployed_;
        pokemonCaughtByType_ = other.pokemonCaughtByType_;
        smallRattataCaught_ = other.smallRattataCaught_;
    }

    public static pb::MessageParser<PlayerStats> Parser
    {
        get { return _parser; }
    }

    public static pbr::MessageDescriptor Descriptor
    {
        get { return global::PokemonGo.RocketAPI.GeneratedCode.PayloadsReflection.Descriptor.MessageTypes[14]; }
    }

    public int Level
    {
        get { return level_; }
        set { level_ = value; }
    }

    public long Experience
    {
        get { return experience_; }
        set { experience_ = value; }
    }

    public long PrevLevelXp
    {
        get { return prevLevelXp_; }
        set { prevLevelXp_ = value; }
    }

    public long NextLevelXp
    {
        get { return nextLevelXp_; }
        set { nextLevelXp_ = value; }
    }

    public float KmWalked
    {
        get { return kmWalked_; }
        set { kmWalked_ = value; }
    }

    public int PokemonsEncountered
    {
        get { return pokemonsEncountered_; }
        set { pokemonsEncountered_ = value; }
    }

    public int UniquePokedexEntries
    {
        get { return uniquePokedexEntries_; }
        set { uniquePokedexEntries_ = value; }
    }

    public int PokemonsCaptured
    {
        get { return pokemonsCaptured_; }
        set { pokemonsCaptured_ = value; }
    }

    public int Evolutions
    {
        get { return evolutions_; }
        set { evolutions_ = value; }
    }

    public int PokeStopVisits
    {
        get { return pokeStopVisits_; }
        set { pokeStopVisits_ = value; }
    }

    public int PokeballsThrown
    {
        get { return pokeballsThrown_; }
        set { pokeballsThrown_ = value; }
    }

    public int EggsHatched
    {
        get { return eggsHatched_; }
        set { eggsHatched_ = value; }
    }

    public int BigMagikarpCaught
    {
        get { return bigMagikarpCaught_; }
        set { bigMagikarpCaught_ = value; }
    }

    public int BattleAttackWon
    {
        get { return battleAttackWon_; }
        set { battleAttackWon_ = value; }
    }

    public int BattleAttackTotal
    {
        get { return battleAttackTotal_; }
        set { battleAttackTotal_ = value; }
    }

    public int BattleDefendedWon
    {
        get { return battleDefendedWon_; }
        set { battleDefendedWon_ = value; }
    }

    public int BattleTrainingWon
    {
        get { return battleTrainingWon_; }
        set { battleTrainingWon_ = value; }
    }

    public int BattleTrainingTotal
    {
        get { return battleTrainingTotal_; }
        set { battleTrainingTotal_ = value; }
    }

    public int PrestigeRaisedTotal
    {
        get { return prestigeRaisedTotal_; }
        set { prestigeRaisedTotal_ = value; }
    }

    public int PrestigeDroppedTotal
    {
        get { return prestigeDroppedTotal_; }
        set { prestigeDroppedTotal_ = value; }
    }

    public int PokemonDeployed
    {
        get { return pokemonDeployed_; }
        set { pokemonDeployed_ = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     TODO: repeated PokemonType ??
    /// </summary>
    public pb::ByteString PokemonCaughtByType
    {
        get { return pokemonCaughtByType_; }
        set { pokemonCaughtByType_ = pb::ProtoPreconditions.CheckNotNull(value, "value"); }
    }

    public int SmallRattataCaught
    {
        get { return smallRattataCaught_; }
        set { smallRattataCaught_ = value; }
    }

    pbr::MessageDescriptor pb::IMessage.Descriptor
    {
        get { return Descriptor; }
    }

    public PlayerStats Clone()
    {
        return new PlayerStats(this);
    }

    public bool Equals(PlayerStats other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, this))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (Level != other.Level) return false;
        if (Experience != other.Experience) return false;
        if (PrevLevelXp != other.PrevLevelXp) return false;
        if (NextLevelXp != other.NextLevelXp) return false;
        if (KmWalked != other.KmWalked) return false;
        if (PokemonsEncountered != other.PokemonsEncountered) return false;
        if (UniquePokedexEntries != other.UniquePokedexEntries) return false;
        if (PokemonsCaptured != other.PokemonsCaptured) return false;
        if (Evolutions != other.Evolutions) return false;
        if (PokeStopVisits != other.PokeStopVisits) return false;
        if (PokeballsThrown != other.PokeballsThrown) return false;
        if (EggsHatched != other.EggsHatched) return false;
        if (BigMagikarpCaught != other.BigMagikarpCaught) return false;
        if (BattleAttackWon != other.BattleAttackWon) return false;
        if (BattleAttackTotal != other.BattleAttackTotal) return false;
        if (BattleDefendedWon != other.BattleDefendedWon) return false;
        if (BattleTrainingWon != other.BattleTrainingWon) return false;
        if (BattleTrainingTotal != other.BattleTrainingTotal) return false;
        if (PrestigeRaisedTotal != other.PrestigeRaisedTotal) return false;
        if (PrestigeDroppedTotal != other.PrestigeDroppedTotal) return false;
        if (PokemonDeployed != other.PokemonDeployed) return false;
        if (PokemonCaughtByType != other.PokemonCaughtByType) return false;
        if (SmallRattataCaught != other.SmallRattataCaught) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public void WriteTo(pb::CodedOutputStream output)
    {
        if (Level != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(8);
            output.WriteInt32(Level);
        }
        if (Experience != 0L)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(16);
            output.WriteInt64(Experience);
        }
        if (PrevLevelXp != 0L)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(24);
            output.WriteInt64(PrevLevelXp);
        }
        if (NextLevelXp != 0L)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(32);
            output.WriteInt64(NextLevelXp);
        }
        if (KmWalked != 0F)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(45);
            output.WriteFloat(KmWalked);
        }
        if (PokemonsEncountered != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(48);
            output.WriteInt32(PokemonsEncountered);
        }
        if (UniquePokedexEntries != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(56);
            output.WriteInt32(UniquePokedexEntries);
        }
        if (PokemonsCaptured != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(64);
            output.WriteInt32(PokemonsCaptured);
        }
        if (Evolutions != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(72);
            output.WriteInt32(Evolutions);
        }
        if (PokeStopVisits != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(80);
            output.WriteInt32(PokeStopVisits);
        }
        if (PokeballsThrown != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(88);
            output.WriteInt32(PokeballsThrown);
        }
        if (EggsHatched != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(96);
            output.WriteInt32(EggsHatched);
        }
        if (BigMagikarpCaught != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(104);
            output.WriteInt32(BigMagikarpCaught);
        }
        if (BattleAttackWon != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(112);
            output.WriteInt32(BattleAttackWon);
        }
        if (BattleAttackTotal != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(120);
            output.WriteInt32(BattleAttackTotal);
        }
        if (BattleDefendedWon != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(128, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(BattleDefendedWon);
        }
        if (BattleTrainingWon != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(136, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(BattleTrainingWon);
        }
        if (BattleTrainingTotal != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(144, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(BattleTrainingTotal);
        }
        if (PrestigeRaisedTotal != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(152, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(PrestigeRaisedTotal);
        }
        if (PrestigeDroppedTotal != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(160, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(PrestigeDroppedTotal);
        }
        if (PokemonDeployed != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(168, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(PokemonDeployed);
        }
        if (PokemonCaughtByType.Length != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(178, 1);
            output.WriteBytes(PokemonCaughtByType);
        }
        if (SmallRattataCaught != 0)
        {
            output.WriteRawTag(184, 1);
            output.WriteInt32(SmallRattataCaught);
        }
    }

    public int CalculateSize()
    {
        var size = 0;
        if (Level != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(Level);
        }
        if (Experience != 0L)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt64Size(Experience);
        }
        if (PrevLevelXp != 0L)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt64Size(PrevLevelXp);
        }
        if (NextLevelXp != 0L)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt64Size(NextLevelXp);
        }
        if (KmWalked != 0F)
        {
            size += 1 + 4;
        }
        if (PokemonsEncountered != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PokemonsEncountered);
        }
        if (UniquePokedexEntries != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(UniquePokedexEntries);
        }
        if (PokemonsCaptured != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PokemonsCaptured);
        }
        if (Evolutions != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(Evolutions);
        }
        if (PokeStopVisits != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PokeStopVisits);
        }
        if (PokeballsThrown != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PokeballsThrown);
        }
        if (EggsHatched != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(EggsHatched);
        }
        if (BigMagikarpCaught != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(BigMagikarpCaught);
        }
        if (BattleAttackWon != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(BattleAttackWon);
        }
        if (BattleAttackTotal != 0)
        {
            size += 1 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(BattleAttackTotal);
        }
        if (BattleDefendedWon != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(BattleDefendedWon);
        }
        if (BattleTrainingWon != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(BattleTrainingWon);
        }
        if (BattleTrainingTotal != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(BattleTrainingTotal);
        }
        if (PrestigeRaisedTotal != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PrestigeRaisedTotal);
        }
        if (PrestigeDroppedTotal != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PrestigeDroppedTotal);
        }
        if (PokemonDeployed != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(PokemonDeployed);
        }
        if (PokemonCaughtByType.Length != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeBytesSize(PokemonCaughtByType);
        }
        if (SmallRattataCaught != 0)
        {
            size += 2 + pb::CodedOutputStream.ComputeInt32Size(SmallRattataCaught);
        }
        return size;
    }

    public void MergeFrom(PlayerStats other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (other.Level != 0)
        {
            Level = other.Level;
        }
        if (other.Experience != 0L)
        {
            Experience = other.Experience;
        }
        if (other.PrevLevelXp != 0L)
        {
            PrevLevelXp = other.PrevLevelXp;
        }
        if (other.NextLevelXp != 0L)
        {
            NextLevelXp = other.NextLevelXp;
        }
        if (other.KmWalked != 0F)
        {
            KmWalked = other.KmWalked;
        }
        if (other.PokemonsEncountered != 0)
        {
            PokemonsEncountered = other.PokemonsEncountered;
        }
        if (other.UniquePokedexEntries != 0)
        {
            UniquePokedexEntries = other.UniquePokedexEntries;
        }
        if (other.PokemonsCaptured != 0)
        {
            PokemonsCaptured = other.PokemonsCaptured;
        }
        if (other.Evolutions != 0)
        {
            Evolutions = other.Evolutions;
        }
        if (other.PokeStopVisits != 0)
        {
            PokeStopVisits = other.PokeStopVisits;
        }
        if (other.PokeballsThrown != 0)
        {
            PokeballsThrown = other.PokeballsThrown;
        }
        if (other.EggsHatched != 0)
        {
            EggsHatched = other.EggsHatched;
        }
        if (other.BigMagikarpCaught != 0)
        {
            BigMagikarpCaught = other.BigMagikarpCaught;
        }
        if (other.BattleAttackWon != 0)
        {
            BattleAttackWon = other.BattleAttackWon;
        }
        if (other.BattleAttackTotal != 0)
        {
            BattleAttackTotal = other.BattleAttackTotal;
        }
        if (other.BattleDefendedWon != 0)
        {
            BattleDefendedWon = other.BattleDefendedWon;
        }
        if (other.BattleTrainingWon != 0)
        {
            BattleTrainingWon = other.BattleTrainingWon;
        }
        if (other.BattleTrainingTotal != 0)
        {
            BattleTrainingTotal = other.BattleTrainingTotal;
        }
        if (other.PrestigeRaisedTotal != 0)
        {
            PrestigeRaisedTotal = other.PrestigeRaisedTotal;
        }
        if (other.PrestigeDroppedTotal != 0)
        {
            PrestigeDroppedTotal = other.PrestigeDroppedTotal;
        }
        if (other.PokemonDeployed != 0)
        {
            PokemonDeployed = other.PokemonDeployed;
        }
        if (other.PokemonCaughtByType.Length != 0)
        {
            PokemonCaughtByType = other.PokemonCaughtByType;
        }
        if (other.SmallRattataCaught != 0)
        {
            SmallRattataCaught = other.SmallRattataCaught;
        }
    }

    public void MergeFrom(pb::CodedInputStream input)
    {
        uint tag;
        while ((tag = input.ReadTag()) != 0)
        {
            switch (tag)
            {
                default:
                    input.SkipLastField();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    {
                        Level = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 16:
                    {
                        Experience = input.ReadInt64();
                        break;
                    }
                case 24:
                    {
                        PrevLevelXp = input.ReadInt64();
                        break;
                    }
                case 32:
                    {
                        NextLevelXp = input.ReadInt64();
                        break;
                    }
                case 45:
                    {
                        KmWalked = input.ReadFloat();
                        break;
                    }
                case 48:
                    {
                        PokemonsEncountered = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 56:
                    {
                        UniquePokedexEntries = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 64:
                    {
                        PokemonsCaptured = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 72:
                    {
                        Evolutions = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 80:
                    {
                        PokeStopVisits = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 88:
                    {
                        PokeballsThrown = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 96:
                    {
                        EggsHatched = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 104:
                    {
                        BigMagikarpCaught = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 112:
                    {
                        BattleAttackWon = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 120:
                    {
                        BattleAttackTotal = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 128:
                    {
                        BattleDefendedWon = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 136:
                    {
                        BattleTrainingWon = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 144:
                    {
                        BattleTrainingTotal = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 152:
                    {
                        PrestigeRaisedTotal = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 160:
                    {
                        PrestigeDroppedTotal = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 168:
                    {
                        PokemonDeployed = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
                case 178:
                    {
                        PokemonCaughtByType = input.ReadBytes();
                        break;
                    }
                case 184:
                    {
                        SmallRattataCaught = input.ReadInt32();
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as PlayerStats);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hash = 1;
        if (Level != 0) hash ^= Level.GetHashCode();
        if (Experience != 0L) hash ^= Experience.GetHashCode();
        if (PrevLevelXp != 0L) hash ^= PrevLevelXp.GetHashCode();
        if (NextLevelXp != 0L) hash ^= NextLevelXp.GetHashCode();
        if (KmWalked != 0F) hash ^= KmWalked.GetHashCode();
        if (PokemonsEncountered != 0) hash ^= PokemonsEncountered.GetHashCode();
        if (UniquePokedexEntries != 0) hash ^= UniquePokedexEntries.GetHashCode();
        if (PokemonsCaptured != 0) hash ^= PokemonsCaptured.GetHashCode();
        if (Evolutions != 0) hash ^= Evolutions.GetHashCode();
        if (PokeStopVisits != 0) hash ^= PokeStopVisits.GetHashCode();
        if (PokeballsThrown != 0) hash ^= PokeballsThrown.GetHashCode();
        if (EggsHatched != 0) hash ^= EggsHatched.GetHashCode();
        if (BigMagikarpCaught != 0) hash ^= BigMagikarpCaught.GetHashCode();
        if (BattleAttackWon != 0) hash ^= BattleAttackWon.GetHashCode();
        if (BattleAttackTotal != 0) hash ^= BattleAttackTotal.GetHashCode();
        if (BattleDefendedWon != 0) hash ^= BattleDefendedWon.GetHashCode();
        if (BattleTrainingWon != 0) hash ^= BattleTrainingWon.GetHashCode();
        if (BattleTrainingTotal != 0) hash ^= BattleTrainingTotal.GetHashCode();
        if (PrestigeRaisedTotal != 0) hash ^= PrestigeRaisedTotal.GetHashCode();
        if (PrestigeDroppedTotal != 0) hash ^= PrestigeDroppedTotal.GetHashCode();
        if (PokemonDeployed != 0) hash ^= PokemonDeployed.GetHashCode();
        if (PokemonCaughtByType.Length != 0) hash ^= PokemonCaughtByType.GetHashCode();
        if (SmallRattataCaught != 0) hash ^= SmallRattataCaught.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    partial void OnConstruction();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return pb::JsonFormatter.ToDiagnosticString(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't see the methods in the debug view. Properties are supposed to be fast to evaluate, and have no side effects. Methods, however, can take parameters and may take any length of time. How would the debugger show the results of `Mutate(bool upsideDown)`?

Comment: `Here how i can see the methods with debug` <- I am not sure what you are asking here? What do you mean by `with debug`?

Comment: I think you're asking for [`GetMethods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx), going by the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see methods in the Auto and Locals View. Methods can have side effects when they get evaluated (properties are ought to have no side effects), so to prevent your application to end up corrupted it doesn't show them.

Only properties and fields are shown. You can call methods yourself in the Watch View.

Comment: Properties have methods in them, they can be computed because they have no parameters. So I would disagree somewhat with your explanation.

Comment: Properties *can* have method calls in them, but they should still be stateless as much as possible.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with the debug view.... state or no state, the debug view can't tell. Secondly you can have the debug view execute queryable results. So I would have said there is limited functionality to what the debug executes and what it does not.